# How to save multiple rows of data with additional user input fields data from a table when click submit in octobercms?

Tags: octobercms

i have a table with an input filed, the data are loaded from a database using the foreach loop, as shown in the image below. Users can enter the amount they want to withdraw for each sub-division. i have one submit button

[image]

if the user enter an amount for any row, i want to get the information (id, balance and the input amount) of every row in the table and submit it into the database.

How can i get them?

```
 {{ form_ajax('onWithdrawal', {id:"form", class: 'form-horizontal', 'data-request-files':true, 'data-request-flash': true}) }}
 <div id="container" class="table-responsive kv-grid-container">
     <table class="kv-grid-table table table-striped kv-table-wrap">
          <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>{{ 'Sub Divisions'|_ }}</th>
                <th>{{ 'Balance'|_ }}</th>
                <th>{{ 'Amount Taken'|_ }}</th>
                <th>{{ 'Withdraw'|_ }}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                            
                            
             {% for log in logs %}
                              
                 <tr id = "{{log.id }}">
                 <td>{{log.name }}</td> 
                 <td>{{log.balance }}</td>
                 <td>{{log.withdraw }}</td>
                 <td><input type="number" min=1000  max="1500" id="item-b"class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="1,000" ></td>
                                       
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
                            
         </tbody>
    </table>
                        
                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default "  data-request="onWithdrawal" data-request-files  style="float:right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>{{ 'Submit'|_ }}
         </button>
                               
    </div>
</div>

{{ form_close() }}
```

php part

```
function onWithdrawal(){
  $user = Auth::getUser();

               $model = new WithdrawLog();
                $model->user_id = $user->id;
                $model->email = $user->email;
                $model->id = ?
                $model->name = ?
                $model->amount = Input::get("amount");
    

          if ($model->save()) {
                         Flash::success('Withdrawal Application successfully sent');  
                         return Redirect::refresh();
                    } else {
                        Flash::error('error');  
                        return Redirect::refresh();
                    }
                    
    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it this way.

in the HTML

```
<td><input type="number" min=1000  max="1500" id="item-b"class="form-control" name="amount[{{ log.id }}]" placeholder="1,000" ></td>
```

For the PHP,i did something like this.

```
function onWithdrawal(){
  $user = Auth::getUser();

               $model = new WithdrawLog();
                $model->user_id = $user->id;
                $model->email = $user->email;

         foreach(post("amount") as $id => $amount){
            if($amount !=""){
                $model->id = $id;
                $model->amount = $amount;
              }
         }

          if ($model->save()) {
                         Flash::success('successfully sent');  
                         return Redirect::refresh();
                    } else {
                        Flash::error('error');  
                        return Redirect::refresh();
                    }
                    
    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are lots of ways to do what you are doing. If you are looking for something secure you should look into validating the rows.

First thing is change your form to a standard HTML form. It is easier to debug.

```
{#{{ form_ajax('onWithdrawal', {id: 'form', class: 'form-horizontal', 'data-request-files':true, 'data-request-flash': true}) }}#}
{{ form_open({request: 'onWithdrawal', id:'form', class: 'form-horizontal', files: 'true'}) }}
```

In your HTML add some hidden elements and group your name's by `commonId[nameValue]`. [Learn more here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/):

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="{{ log.id }}[id]" value="{{ log.id }}"><input type="number" min=1000  max="1500" id="item-b"class="form-control" name="{{ log.id }}[amount]" placeholder="1,000" ></td>
```

Now your PHP can look something like this:

```
function onWithdrawal(){
    foreach(Input::except('_session_key', '_token') as $row) {

        $user = Auth::getUser();

        $model = WithdrawLog::find($row['id']); //If they exist you only need to find them.
        $model->user_id = $user->id;
        $model->email = $user->email;
        $model->id = $row['id'];
        $model->amount = $row['amount'];

        $model->save();
        
    }
    // Should prolly look into validating or checking which records were not updated.
    Flash::success('Withdrawal Application successfully sent');  
    return Redirect::refresh();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but i get this error `Illegal string offset 'id'` when i submit it. also in the php code, i am submitting the withdrawal application into another database thats why i used the `$model = new WithdrawLog();` to create it as a new record.

Comment: @Karamokanagi Oh sorry I misunderstood what exactly your end result was. You should definitely tweak my code to what precisely need as it was more of an example. Also use `dd($row)` to figure out what you are receiving in the row.